# How to identify what slot type a particular PC card is?

Tags: graphics-card, expansion-cards

Is there a good place to go to identify what kind of slot my spare video card uses?

A site that shows pictures of the various slot types so I can identify this one?

Comment: Just to clarify: GPU stands for Graphics Proccessing Unit, and is not a slot type.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See if you can find your graphics card slot/connector in this hardware identification chart:

http://sonic840.deviantart.com/art/Computer-hardware-poster-1-7-111402099

Specifically, check the rightmost column, in the sections titled "Peripheral Cards" and "Desktop Card Slots."

Your spare video card probably uses a PCI-Express x16, AGP, or PCI slot.  (listed in order from fastest/newest to slowest/oldest)

There are a few (very few) motherboards with integrated video that also support special pass-through riser cards.  If that's the case, your best to identify the slot bet is to find a model number on the card or motherboard, and search on Google or eBay.  But if you just need a card, you can get a card that will fit in any of your other expansion slots.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

[PCIe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) card (x16):

[image]

PCIe slot (x16):

[image]

[AGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_Graphics_Port) card:

[image]

AGP slot:

[image]

PCI card:

[image]

PCI slot:

[image]

And just for the [craic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/craic#Noun), here's an ISA graphics card :)

[image]

Comment: Nothing on PCI 1 or 4xe? or whatever they're called now...